# How to use Share Status in windows phone 8.1 universal app

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

In windows phone 8 we use `ShareStatusTask` sharing statuses. as `Microsoft.Ppone.Task` is not available in windows phone 8.1 so how can we share status in windows Phone 8.1 Universal app? what the equivalent of this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new way of sharing is like the one in Windows store apps. Windows can ask the program if it has anything to share, and what that might be. For this you need to implement a function in your views which can share and set it in the DataTransferManager. A complete code might look like:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // Register the current page as a share source.
    _dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
    _dataTransferManager.DataRequested += OnDataRequested;
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // Unregister the current page as a share source.
    _dataTransferManager.DataRequested -= OnDataRequested;
}

protected void OnDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Request.Data.Properties.Title = "Some title";
    e.Request.Data.Properties.Description = "Some description"; // Optional 
    e.Request.Data.SetUri(new Uri("http://www.some_uri.com"));
}
```

Here this are the [LINK1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thunbrynt/archive/2014/04/16/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-contracts.aspx), [LINK2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datatransfermanager.getforcurrentview) & [LINK3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871368.aspx) which will give you more info. Hope this helps.